# How can I use model relationships to associate my preorder model with my customer model in the admin without creating new objects each time

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many

How can I associate a customer with a preorder object, while not creating a bunch of objects for that model? When the `ManyToMany` relationship is used in the admin change page, rather than allowing me to associate multiple customers with one Preorder, when I try to associate a customer with an instance of the Preorder model, it seems to create a new object, instead of updating the current Preorder instance to include a new customer to associate with it. I want something like this:

> (**customer: John, id=3**) is associated with (**Preorder: NewItem, id=1**), and (**customer: Kim, id=5**) is also associated with (**Preorder: NewItem, id=1**). So John and Kim have both preordered **NewItem where id=1**, and if I were to select **Preorder:NewItem, id=1** from a table, it would show that John and Kim have preorderd this item

I basically want to show a list that  displays all customers that have preordered a specific product. Instead, at least with the `ManyToMany` field, when I click add next Many field display, it prompts me to create a new Preorder to associate with that customer, instead of selecting an already existing one. This results in each customer having the same preorder names associated, but these preorders will have different pk on the db table.
I have a Customer and Preorder model:

```
class Preorder(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=None)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product


class Customer(models.Model):
    preorders = models.ManyToManyField(Preorder, blank=True, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, default='')
    credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=None, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Store Credit')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Hi juju, could you elaborate on what you mean by: "associate a customer with a preorder object from another model, while not creating a bunch of objects for that model".

Comment: @MichaelRoberts I very poorly tried to give an example lol. Please let me know if that makes it more clear for you, or if I need to explain it better.

Comment: Yes - that's more than possible (either way you'll still need to have multiple records) but you will in effect have a lookup on the `Customer`.`preorders` field.

Comment: Hi juju - check out my answer below and see if this helps you in any way! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of ways you could approach this, but it feels like you have your ManyToMany field the wrong way around:

```
class Preorder(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=None)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, )
    customer = models.ManyToManyField(Customer, blank=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

That way, you have one pre-order with two customers (John and Kim) - so you're not duplicating your pre-order objects, or your user objects!

Then, in `views.py`:

```
def preorders(request, product):

    context = {}

    preorders = Preorder.object.filter(product=product)

    return ...
```

And in `urls.py` something like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^preorders/(?P<product>\d+)/$', views.preorders, name='customer_preorders_by_product')),
    ...
]
```

And your template:

```
{% for preorder in preorders %}
<ul>
    preorder.product
    <li>{% for customer in preorder.customer.all %}{{ customer }}{% endfor %}</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: I see! That is helpful. I think I might have had the Many relationship a little mixed. Do you know how I could go about displaying the list in the admin change page of the model? So each preorder item, in the admin section has a list of people who have preorded it. I assum I'd have to do this using some type of custom model Form for the admin?